# Approvals in Power Automate - second set of options

Tags: office365, power-automate

I'm working on a approval process in Power automate. Short description of the flow is the following:

1. If team finishes a task, send approval to team leader.
2. If team leader accepts the result, send another approval to the CEO, Owner or Manager

At the moment, I am able to send 2nd approval only to "hardcoded" people, but I would like to add an option to 1st approval, where the team leader could decide Approver (CEO or Owner or Manager), not all of them.

In short, 1st approval request would have 2 sets of buttons / options:

1. accept / reject
2. CEO / Owner / Manager

If team leader accepts the results, 2nd approval would be sent to chosen approver.

Is this possible? Or is there a way to add user input to Approval request?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick

1. If the first approval is approved, send "Email with options" to the team leader with the choice of final approver
2. Get the user information of the final approver based on the name in option selected
3. Send an approval to this person based on the email retrieved in the previous step